# Get total price added up with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Newbie on JS and got really stuck. 
I have a plus and a minus button that adds up products. But I need that the result of this total price to adds up accordingly. And some of the products can only be bought with multiples of 2, 5 or 10.

I have here my html with 2 of my products. One that can only be sold with multiples of 5 and the other, multiple of 10.

```
<!-- Product #6 -->
      <div class="item">
        <div class="buttons">
          <span class="delete-btn"></span>
          <span class="like-btn"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="image">
          <img src="intem-6.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>

        <div class="description">
          <span>DLT-19 Heavy Blaster Rifle</span>
          <span>Brown</span>
        </div>

        <div class="quantity">
          <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button">
            <img src="plus-btn.png" alt="" />
          </button>
          <input type="text" name="name" value="1">
          <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button">
            <img src="minus-btn.png" alt="" />
          </button>
        </div>

        <div id="multiple5" class="total-price">$5800</div>
      </div>

        <!-- Product #7 -->
      <div class="item">
        <div class="buttons">
          <span class="delete-btn"></span>
          <span class="like-btn"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="image">
          <img src="item-7.jpg" alt="" >
        </div>

        <div class="description">
          <span>DL-44 Heavy Blaster Pistol</span>
          <span>Brown</span>
        </div>

        <div class="quantity">
          <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button">
            <img src="plus-btn.png" alt="" />
          </button>
          <input type="text" name="name" value="1">
          <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button">
            <img src="minus-btn.png" alt="" />
          </button>
        </div>

        <div id="multiple10" class="total-price">$1500</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my jQuery that adds up 1 on.click of my buttons.

```
$('.minus-btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var $input = $this.closest('div').find('input');
        var value = parseInt($input.val());

    if (value >= 1) {
            value = value - 1;
        } else {
            value = 0;
        }

        $input.val(value);

      });

    $('.plus-btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var $input = $this.closest('div').find('input');
        var value = parseInt($input.val());

        if (value < 100) {
            value = value + 1;
        } else {
            value =100;
        }

        $input.val(value);
    });
```

I tried doing separately along with my searches but couldn't implement this on my other code. Just want the result to add up and decrease the price along with the on.click event of my buttons.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>

        <style>
            *{
                font-size: 25px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <button id="plus"> + </button>
        <input id="quantity" type="number" value='1'>    
        <button id="minus"> - </button>
        <div id="total">5</div>


        <script>

            let plus = document.getElementById('plus');    
            let quantityEle = document.getElementById('quantity');    
            let minus = document.getElementById('minus');    
            let total = document.getElementById('total');    

            let quantity = quantityEle.value;
            let price = 5;

            plus.addEventListener('click', function(){
                quantity++; 
                quantityEle.value = quantity;
                total.innerHTML = price * quantity;

            });

            minus.addEventListener('click', function(){
                if(quantity > 1)
                quantity--; 
                quantityEle.value = quantity;
                total.innerHTML = price * quantity;
            });

            quantityEle.addEventListener('change', function(){
                quantity = quantityEle.value;
                total.innerHTML = price * quantity;
            });

            var total = $this.closest('div').find('div');

        </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you don't need jquery for any of this. Note that `jquery` is NOT synonymous with `javascript`. Javascript is the language, jquery is a library (which you don't need for most of the time now days).

Comment: You might want to take a quick basics course in javascript. Here is one where you [build a calculator :)](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-an-html-calculator-app-from-scratch-using-javascript-4454b8714b98/). Here's a [great resource for basic javascript](http://javascript.info/), you should probably start with this one.

Comment: Your second attempt [seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/otdxswm0/), except for one line that causes errors: `var total = $this.closest('div').find('div');`.

Comment: You redeclare `let total` with `var total =`. The error even shows up in your console.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go!

```js
$('.minus-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $parent = $(this).closest('.item');
  var $input = $parent.find('input');
  var $total = $parent.find('.total-price span');
  var value = parseInt($input.val());

  if (value >= 1) {
    value = value - 1;
  } else {
    value = 0;
  }

  $input.val(value);
  $total.html(value);
  calcTotal();
});

$('.plus-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $parent = $(this).closest('.item');
  var $input = $parent.find('input');
  var $total = $parent.find('.total-price span');
  var value = parseInt($input.val());

  if (value < 100) {
    value = value + 1;
  } else {
    value = 100;
  }

  $input.val(value);
  $total.html(value);
  calcTotal();
});

function calcTotal() {
  let total = 0;
  $(".total-price span").each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).html());
  });
  $('#total').html('$' + total);
}
```

```css
#total {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Product #6 -->
<div class="item">
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="delete-btn"></span>
    <span class="like-btn"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img src="intem-6.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="description">
    <span>DLT-19 Heavy Blaster Rifle</span>
    <span>Brown</span>
  </div>

  <div class="quantity">
    <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button">
            <img src="plus-btn.png" alt="" /> +
          </button>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="1">
    <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button">
            <img src="minus-btn.png" alt="" /> -
          </button>
  </div>

  <div id="multiple5" class="total-price">$<span>1</span></div>
</div>

<!-- Product #7 -->
<div class="item">
  <div class="buttons">
    <span class="delete-btn"></span>
    <span class="like-btn"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img src="item-7.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="description">
    <span>DL-44 Heavy Blaster Pistol</span>
    <span>Brown</span>
  </div>

  <div class="quantity">
    <button class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button">
            <img src="plus-btn.png" alt="" /> + 
          </button>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="1">
    <button class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button">
            <img src="minus-btn.png" alt="" /> -
          </button>
  </div>

  <div id="multiple10" class="total-price">$<span>1</span></div>
</div>

<div>
  Total: <span id="total">$2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*I think your question is really badly asked.*
From what I understand, you seek to write an equivalence of jQuery in JS 'vanila' to increment decrement of (2, 5, 10) quantities and realize the corresponding totals.

so here is "my solution":

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('button.minus')
  .forEach(bt=>
    {
    bt.onclick=e=>
      {
      let P_parent = e.target.parentNode
        , Inc      = parseInt(P_parent.dataset.increment)
        , U_price  = parseFloat(P_parent.dataset.price).toFixed(2)
        , val      = parseInt(P_parent.querySelector('.quantity').value)

      if (val > 0)
        {
        val -= Inc
        P_parent.querySelector('.quantity').value = val
        P_parent.querySelector('.total').textContent = '$ '+ (val * U_price).toFixed(2)
        } 
      }
    })

document
  .querySelectorAll('button.plus')
  .forEach(bt=>
    {
    bt.onclick=e=>
      {
      let P_parent = e.target.parentNode
        , Inc      = parseInt(P_parent.dataset.increment)
        , U_price  = parseFloat(P_parent.dataset.price).toFixed(2)
        , Max      = parseInt(P_parent.dataset.max)
        , val      = parseInt(P_parent.querySelector('.quantity').value)

      if (val < Max)
        {
        val += Inc
        P_parent.querySelector('.quantity').value = val
        P_parent.querySelector('.total').textContent = '$ '+ (val * U_price).toFixed(2)
        } 
      }
    })
```

```css
body { font: 14px sans-serif; padding: 1em; }
h3 { margin: 1.5em 0 0 0; }
input.quantity { width:4em; text-align: right  }
.total { display: inline-block; width: 6em; text-align: right; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; margin-left: .5em }
p > button { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<h3>by 2</h3>
<p data-increment="2" data-max=50 data-price="11">
  <input class="quantity" type="text" value='0' readonly>
  <button class="minus">-</button>
  <button class="plus">+</button>
  unit price : $11
  <span class="total">$ 0</span>
</p>

<h3>by 5</h3>
<p data-increment="5" data-max=80 data-price="5.23">
  <input class="quantity" type="text" value='0' readonly>
  <button class="minus">-</button>
  <button class="plus">+</button>
  unit price : $5.23
  <span class="total">$ 0</span>
</p>

<h3>by 10</h3>
<p data-increment="10" data-max=100 data-price="3.12">
  <input class="quantity" type="text" value='0' readonly>
  <button class="minus">-</button>
  <button class="plus">+</button>
  unit price : $3.12
  <span class="total">$ 0</span>
</p>
```